# OWIN/Katana & BasicAuthentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, katana

I am trying to achieve a simple task:
Secure my ASP.NET WEBAPI (built on top of Katana) with BASIC Auth.
I know I could implement my own middleware or message handler or whatever. However I'm wondering if such a simple task is not already implemented?
I found multiple samples on the web that shows how simple it should be. But all of these samples refer to a nuget package named microsoft.owin.security.basic which I can not find anywhere!?
Can you help me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all you should consider NOT doing basic authentication directly - but rather use the OAuth2 authorization server approach - read this first:

http://leastprivilege.com/2013/11/13/authorization-servers-are-good-for-you-and-your-web-apis/

http://leastprivilege.com/2013/11/13/embedding-a-simple-usernamepassword-authorization-server-in-web-api-v2/

If you still want to do basic auth - then in this repo you will find an implementation for Katana:

https://github.com/thinktecture/Thinktecture.IdentityModel/tree/master/source/Thinktecture.IdentityModel.Owin

nuget: Thinktecture.IdentityModel.Owin

Comment: hi dominic, thank you very much for your answer. why should i not use basic authentication directly? is oauth2 not a bit overdimensioned for a simple service which communicates by ssl and just should have a basic authentication mechanism? Thank you for the related links, very interesting.

Comment: I assume you haven't read the posts yet? All the answers are in there...but in a nutshell - in basic auth you have to transmit the password on every request - this is not really feasible if your passwords are properly protected and stored on the server. My 2nd post shows how you essentially get a "cookies for web apis" approach in 10 lines of code. That is "overdimensionied"?

Comment: okey, thank you! I'll read the post first, instead of asking obselete questions :) Thank you very much

Comment: Using OAuth2 is impossible when you have a client that does not support it. And there are plenty of those, be sure.

Comment: Like Alexey pointed out sometimes the developers have no choice, i.e. I have to integrate with a framework what uses basic auth so my API has to support it. It is weird that basic authentication is not built in to OWIN.

Comment: @user3285954 I've used the Thinktecture package in an OWIN/Katana app and can vouch that it couldn't be simpler if owin came with it out of the box!

Comment: @leastprivilege "this is not really feasible if your passwords are properly protected and stored on the server" - this is incorrect. You can use salted+hashed passwords on the server with Basic Authentication - it's conceptually the same as logging into a website by entering your username and password into a `<form>` the way humans do. I think you mean *on the client*. Still, there are ways around this (such as challenge-response but still using Basic Authentication only as an auth transport). OAuth2 is overkill and too complicated for many small projects.

Comment: Link to https://github.com/thinktecture/Thinktecture.IdentityModel/tree/master/source/Thinktecture.IdentityModel.Owin is broken, but NuGet package still available

Answer (score 1):

For those looking for a streamlined way of doing basic auth using Web API+OWIN+Katana, use the excellent Thinktecture.IdentityModel.Owin.BasicAuthentication library.

NuGet: [HERE](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Thinktecture.IdentityModel.Owin.BasicAuthentication/) and the 
source: [HERE](https://github.com/IdentityModel/Thinktecture.IdentityModel/tree/edbec63bc41b9706b465873d8df5a97d446bec9d/source/Owin.BasicAuthentication)